# Economically computing $d\beta$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives, exterior-algebra

> $\displaystyle \beta = z\frac{x dy \wedge dz + y dz \wedge dx + z dx \wedge dy}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{2}}$
>
> Show that $d\beta=0$.

So, let $r=x^2+y^2+z^2$,

$\begin{align}
\displaystyle d\beta &= d(z\frac{x dy \wedge dz + y dz \wedge dx + z dx \wedge dy}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{2}}) \\
&= d(\frac{zx dy \wedge dz + zy dz \wedge dx + z^2 dx \wedge dy}{r^{2}}) \\
&= d(\frac{zx dy \wedge dz + zy dz \wedge dx + z^2 dx \wedge dy}{r^{2}}) \\
&= d(\frac{zx}{r^2}) \wedge dy \wedge dz + d(\frac{zy}{r^2}) \wedge dz \wedge dx + d(\frac{z^2}{r^2}) \wedge dx \wedge dy \\
\end{align}
$

Is there a better of doing this as I dont really want to have to crunch $d(\frac{zx}{r^2})$ with the product rule?

Comment: Link with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060725/poincar%C3%A9-lemma-problems-and-computing-contractions-in-an-economical-way

Comment: Note that, in eg the first term, you only need to take the partial with respect to $x$; the other terms die because of the wedge product.

Comment: Is it allowed to use deRham cohomology?

Comment: No I would rather not use deRham cohomology. I think it is too advanced for my purposes. I am just looking at what it is on wikipedia now!

Comment: I think that @MikeMiller's answer/comment was what I was looking for.

Comment: I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, in each term, we've written for instance $df \wedge dy \wedge dz$. Because $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz$, and $dy \wedge dy = 0, dz \wedge dz = 0$, we see that $$df \wedge dy \wedge dz = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx \wedge dy \wedge dz.$$ So ultimately for this computation you only need to take three partials, not nine.

The key here is that whenever you've written $df \wedge dx_i$ for some $dx_i$, you don't need to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$, since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i \wedge dx_i = 0$.

Comment: should be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i \wedge dx_j = 0$

Comment: @janmarqz Hm? No it shouldn't, that's not true unless $i=j$ (or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = 0$).

Comment: it was in my mind $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i \wedge dx_i\wedge dx_j = 0$ with not $i$-summation

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm not summing over anything here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=z(x,y,z)/r^2$. Then $\beta=i(X)\Omega$ where $\Omega=dx\wedge dy \wedge dz$ is the volume element of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $i$ is the [interior product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product). Then the definition of divergence operator says $$d(i(X)\Omega)=\operatorname{div}(X)\Omega$$
So to show $d\beta=0$ is equivalent to show $\operatorname{div}(X)=0$ and we have
$$\operatorname{div}(X)=\operatorname{grad}(z)\cdot (x,y,z)/r^2+z \operatorname{div}((x,y,z)/r^2)$$
$$=(0,0,1)\cdot\frac{(x,y,z)}{r^2}+z\sum_{x,y,z}\frac{r^2-x\cdot 2r\cdot 2x}{r^4}$$
$$=\frac{z}{r^2}+z\frac{3r^2-4r\sum_{x,y,z}x^2}{r^4}$$
$$=\frac{z}{r^2}+z\frac{3r^2-4r^2}{r^4}$$
$$=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a more understandable way to see this is to parametrize $\Bbb R^3-\{0\}$ by spherical coordinates: 
$$(x,y,z) = f(r,\phi,\theta)= (r\sin\phi\cos\theta,r\sin\phi\sin\theta,r\cos\phi).$$
Then $f^*\beta = (r\cos\phi)\dfrac{r^3\sin\phi\, d\phi\wedge d\theta}{r^4} = \cos\phi\sin\phi\,d\phi\wedge d\theta$. So it's clear, then, that $f^*(d\beta) = d(f^*\beta) = 0$, and, since $f$ is a diffeomorphism almost everywhere in space, we must have $d\beta = 0$.